# Roslyn compilation speed

Tags: c#, compilation, roslyn

I'm using the Roslyn engine to run some code dynamically. I'm specifically using the Session.Execute functionality. While it all works great, the first time it runs it takes up to 3 seconds. Is there anything I can do to improve this? Subsequent runs seem to perform much quicker but as I'm using it in a website I need to keep it quick.

```
        ScriptEngine roslynEngine = new ScriptEngine();
        Roslyn.Scripting.Session Session = roslynEngine.CreateSession(Field);
        Session.AddReference(Field.GetType().Assembly);
        Session.AddReference("System.Web");
        Session.ImportNamespace("System");
        Session.ImportNamespace("System.Web");
        Session.ImportNamespace("...");

        try
        {
            var result = (string)Session.Execute(EvaluateString);
        }
```

Comment: Because compilation takes some time it's unavoidable. You can only try to *pre-compile* that.  E.g. don't do this on button click, but compile it in background when application starts.

Comment: I have somewhat improved this by creating a thread which spins up a dummy session when the user logs in and that seems to improve the initial load when it's first called but any further suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Great minds! Thanks @Sinatr that's what I decided to do!

Comment: It looks like you're using a much older build of Roslyn.  Switch to the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis packages.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks. I used this as the articles I found online related to what I wanted to do indicated it was the fastest option. Do you have any good examples for what I'm trying to do? See I'm setting a Session and passing in a class instance that I manipulate. Thanks again.